# Rust struct to lambda_http

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, rust, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use lambda_http but having an issue with it.

Basically, I'm trying to create a service_fn by passing a Service trait implemented object to it for a structure that holds state. But it seems to be tripping on std::marker::Send

```
struct Handler {
    db: aws_sdk_dynamodb::Client,
    s3: aws_sdk_s3::Client,
}

impl Handler {
  ..some_stuff..
}

pub trait Service {
    fn route<T>(&self, data: T) -> serde_json::Value;
}

impl Service for Handler {
    fn route<Request>(&self, req: Request) -> serde_json::Value {
        json!({ "error": "Route not found" })
    }
}

pub async fn run(service: Arc<impl Service>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let func = service_fn(|req| lambda_handler(req, service.clone()));
    lambda_http::run(func).await?;

    Ok(())
}

pub(crate) async fn lambda_handler(
    evt: Request,
    svc: Arc<impl Service>,
) -> Result<impl IntoResponse, Error> {
  
  let reply = svc.route(evt);
  let response = LambdaResponse::builder().(..some_stuff..).body(reply.to_string()).unwrap();

  Ok(response)
}
```

For some reason this doesnt quite work and its tied to synchronization but not sure how to fix it.

```
Compiling runtime v0.1.0 (/home/xyz/Documents/lservice/runtime)
warning: unused import: `serde_json::json`
  --> runtime/src/lib.rs:12:5
   |
12 | use serde_json::json;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> runtime/src/lib.rs:21:22
    |
21  |     lambda_http::run(func).await?;
    |                      ^^^^ future returned by `lambda_handler` is not `Send`
    |
note: captured value is not `Send`
   --> runtime/src/lib.rs:29:5
    |
29  |     svc: Arc<impl Service>,
    |     ^^^ has type `Arc<impl Service>` which is not `Send`
note: required by a bound in `lambda_http::run`
   --> /home/xyz/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lambda_http-0.7.1/src/lib.rs:185:16
    |
185 |     S::Future: Send + 'a,
    |                ^^^^ required by this bound in `lambda_http::run`
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
19  | pub async fn run(service: Arc<impl Service + std::marker::Sync>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    |                                            +++++++++++++++++++

error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> runtime/src/lib.rs:21:22
    |
21  |     lambda_http::run(func).await?;
    |                      ^^^^ future returned by `lambda_handler` is not `Send`
    |
note: captured value is not `Send`
   --> runtime/src/lib.rs:29:5
    |
29  |     svc: Arc<impl Service>,
    |     ^^^ has type `Arc<impl Service>` which is not `Send`
note: required by a bound in `lambda_http::run`
   --> /home/xyz/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lambda_http-0.7.1/src/lib.rs:185:16
    |
185 |     S::Future: Send + 'a,
    |                ^^^^ required by this bound in `lambda_http::run`
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
19  | pub async fn run(service: Arc<impl Service + std::marker::Send>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    |                                            +++++++++++++++++++

warning: `runtime` (lib) generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `runtime` due to 2 previous errors; 1 warning emitted
```

This does however work if I just pass dynamodb.clone() to it directly rather than nested inside the Handler struct so I know it probably needs me to implement Send on Handler, but not sure if I'm on the right track here so need a little help on the way forward.

<# **UPDATE** #>

One thing that made this eventually work, was by just protecting the Handler with a Arc<Mutex>. Since it was complaining about a value not being able to pass between threads safely, I just locked it before sending it. Though I can't shake the feeling that this is a sledgehammer approach, especially given if I use lambda_runtime::run (instead of lambda_http::run) this seems to work with just a simple Arc::clone().

<# **UPDATE 2** #>

A suggestion by @Mikdore to also implement Sync as a supertrait did the trick. Now it doesnt need any external locks and just works as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to implement `Send`. And you almost always probably shouldn't. If all members of your struct are `Send`, rust will implement it for you automatically. The compiler tells you what the problem is:

```
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
19  | pub async fn run(service: Arc<impl Service + std::marker::Send>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    |                                              +++++++++++++++++++
```

Any arbitrary type could in theory implement `Service`. Not all of those types are `Send`. You can, as the compiler tells you, restrict your function to take `Arc<impl Service + Send>`. However, perhaps more sensibly, you can also make `Service` a supertrait of `Send`, by doing:

```rust
trait Service: Send {
    //...
}
```

This way, every type implementing `Service` is required to implement `Send`, and you can use `impl Service` in async contexts.

Comment: I had tried that but I dont think its the source of the issue. On making a Service a supertrait, I still get this: **future returned by `lambda_handler` is not `Send`**. If I comment out the svc parameter from lambda_handler, it seems to compile. So its either tied to the Service trait or the Arc but it still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Kenter I ran your code locally. You need to make it a supertrait of `Send` and `Sync`, then it works

Comment: Interesting .. let me try that!

Comment: That worked! What's the reasoning behind that though - does implementing both those traits make it equivalent to locking the object across thread boundaries?

Comment: @Kenter No, those traits are just to inform the compiler and library writers about properties of the type's implementation. You can learn more about them here https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html

Comment: @Kenter So, I didn't know this, but `Arc` will only implement `Send`/`Sync` if `T` is *both*.    That's the reason you still got 'lambda_handler is not Send', and why you also require sync